# Access to a ressource in Android application

Tags: android, android-resources

I have tried to use the gpuimage for Android. the issue is not related to gpuimage but it happens at this moment. I'm trying to build an image filter but just using an image as overlay on the original image.

```
  GPUImageColorDodgeBlendFilter tmp = new GPUImageColorDodgeBlendFilter();
  tmp.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.hipster));
```

My issue is that I need to access to the file called hipster.png located in res/drawable/hipster.png

I would like to avoid using decodeResource because this image will be always the same and I'm want to avoid using context as the filter class is builtin inside a lib aar and I reuse it in my app.

Any idea ?

I have tried to use the context coming from an activity but it's crashing and I think that context is useless in that case

Thanks

Comment: thanks there is no documentation without your question on gpuimageblend filter...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Seb I will tell you how I do it. The only difference is that I use the context, but I pass it as a parameter in certain parts of my code and I don't have any problem.

```
getResources().getIdentifier(<nameOfImage>, "drawable", getPackageName())
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks  acostela but to use it I'm back again to be linked to context. as the filter will be in an aar, I do not want to be linked to a context. getResources is not working if no context

Comment: and can you use applicationContext() or baseContext()?? I don't know if you can access to a Resource in Android without context